# Apache's ForceType OR RewriteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

If I have **abc.php** file but I want it to be accessed as **js** file over the web like
http://xyz.com/abc.js?m=1&x=3
The for this purpose Apache's **ForceType** is better OR **RewriteRule**???

I know both works but want to know which one is correct for this purpose & which one perform better in terms of **speed**.

Answer (score 0):

For this I would prefer a RewriteRule as you don't force all php files to act as a js

RewriteRule ^/?abc.js.*$ http://xyz.com/abc.php?$1 [PT,L] should work fine for that.

Comment: I can control that by explicit files ForceType like 

`<Files "abc.js" >
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>`